# Return and delete all key-value pairs whose tuple keys contain a given element

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Given a dictionary keyed by 2-element tuples, I want to return all the key-value pairs whose keys contain a given element.

For example, the dictionary can be:

```
tupled_dict = {('a',1):1, ('a',2):0, ('b',1):1, ('c',4):0}
```

and the given element is `'a'`, then the key-value pairs that should be returned would be:

```
('a',1):1, ('a',2):0
```

What is the fastest code to do this?

EDIT:

In addition, as a related sub-question, I am interested in the fastest way to delete all such key-value pairs given an element of the keys. Obviously, once I have the results of the above, I can use a loop to delete each dictionary item one by one, but I wonder if there is a short-cut way to do it.

Comment: What have you [tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get those ones:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in tupled_dict.iteritems() if 'a' in k}
{('a', 1): 1, ('a', 2): 0}
```

Similarly, to delete the other ones:

```
>>> tupled_dict = {k: v for k, v in tupled_dict.iteritems() if 'a' not in k}
>>> tupled_dict
{('b', 1): 1, ('c', 4): 0}
```

Comment: If the dict can contain keys other than tuples (for example, strings) then you might need to swap the `in` keyword for different logic.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, the deletion will create a new dictionary and assign that to the `tupled_dict`? What about in-place deletion? Would that be any faster?

Comment: That probably depends on what proportion of the entries will be deleted.  You can check it yourself with `timeit`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it for performance, but I suggest you start by getting a baseline using a for loop, and then another with [dict comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) .

```
>>> {k:v for k, v in tupled_dict.iteritems() if k[0] == 'a'}
{('a', 1): 1, ('a', 2): 0}
```

Comment: Strictly interpreting the question, this wouldn't work if 'a' were the second element of a key tuple.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will work even if 'a' isn't the first element in a key tuple:

```
from operator import methodcaller

contains_a = methodcaller('__contains__', 'a')
keys = filter(contains_a, tupled_dict)
new_dict = dict(zip(keys, map(tupled_dict.get, keys))
```